# how to revert back an update in laravel

Tags: laravel, package

i have updated a http client package to the latest version.but after the update the i start getting errors on my system.how can i revert back to the previous version before the update.my laravel version of my project is 5.8 while the http client package is in the latest version (7.4.1)..

```
                 $body = array(
                'name' => $data['product_name'], 
                'prdcategory_id' => $data['category'], 
                'prdsubcategory_id' => $data['subcategory'],
                'prdprdcategory_id' => $data['prdcategory'],
                'brand_id' => $data['prdbrand'],
                'description' => $data['description']);
                $response = Http::post($url, $body);
                $jsonResponse = $response->object();
```

here is the versions i have edited in the composer.json [image: where i have changed to version 5.8],

the vesrion is still 7.4.1 even after composer install[image: the version is still 7.4.1 after composer install]

Comment: you want to revert the update of laravel or the http client package?

Comment: @MátyásGrőger the http client package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert back an update of a package go to composer.json, and find your package there. Change the version, and run composer install.

In your case:

```
"http client package name": "5.8"
```

Dont forget to remove this char in the beginning of the version: ^. With the character it means at least version 5.8, but it will update to latest

Comment: it doesnt revert its still 7.4.1

Comment: did you composer install run correctly, without failure? Did you give the correct package name?

Comment: have a look on the question i have added the images

Comment: "http client package name": "5.8" the 5.8 here represents the laravel version of my project?

Comment: still the same version 7.4.1..i want to http/client fo laravel version 5.8

Comment: you are right i was missing something small